# Why tensor core prefer NHWC format rather than NCHW format?

Tags: deep-learning, gpu, nvidia

I read [this guide](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/performance/dl-performance-convolutional/index.html) and it says:

> We recommend using the NHWC format where possible

also

> NCHW layouts can still be operated on by Tensor Cores, but include some overhead due to automatic transpose operations

So, I have a question. Why tensor core prefer NHWC format rather than NCHW format?

thanks!

Comment: sounds like they are just designed for this format

Comment: thanks, but i would like to know why they are  designed for this format.

Comment: Probably because a lot of tensor operations like convolutions use all the channels at once so putting the channels close together in memory is more sensible. Just a guess